# How do I set the format of log timestamp within Monolog on Symfony framework

Tags: symfony, monolog

I will premise this with the fact that I am new to Symfony but have been using Laravel for some years.

Is it possible to change the format of the log timestamp string through configuration in Symfony (I'm sure it is). I am getting log files out that look like this…

```
[2022-10-18T09:11:04.228289+00:00] app.DEBUG: a message [] []
```

I would like to format them like this…

```
[2022-10-18 09:11:04] app.DEBUG: a message [] []
```

I am not sure if this is the relevant setting, I suspect it is part of it, but this is the LineFormatter class within Monolog

```
class LineFormatter extends NormalizerFormatter
{
    public const SIMPLE_FORMAT = "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n";
```

I assume this bit is formatting the timestamp [%datetime%] and is being pulled from a system wide configuration. If this is the case, does anyone know how I can override it?

Using Symfony 6 btw

Thanks in advance

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on stackoverflow Gary.

Monolog is a library. Symfony imports libraries via a Bundle. You can configure them via the yaml files in the config subdirectory.

To know which options exists, you have three solutions :

1. Google method. Search the bundle documentation, but in your case, no words about it.
2. Brutus method: put any value to get an error message. You should see that an option like `use_milliseconds` exists (I cannot try it without my dev computer), but I already use the Brutus method :)

```yaml
# config/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    foo: bar
```

3. Horatio Caine method: look in the source of monolog bundle, there is always a file describing the available options. In your case, I found solution in the `monolog.xml file :

```xml
# vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Resources/config/monolog.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="monolog.logger" parent="monolog.logger_prototype" public="false">
            <argument index="0">app</argument>
            <call method="useMicrosecondTimestamps">
                <argument>%monolog.use_microseconds%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
...
```

I cannot try it on my phone, but it should solve your problem:

```yaml
# config/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    use_microseconds: false
```

edit: Since I found this `use_microseconds` config options, I just find on a old documentation an article about it:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/logging/disable_microsecond_precision.html

If you want to remove UTC, you could create your own Formatter. The handler uses a Formatter to format the record before logging it. All Monolog handlers use an instance of Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter by default but you can replace it. Your new formatter must implement Monolog\Formatter\FormatterInterface. [Here is the doc with a sample.](https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/logging/monolog.html#changing-the-formatter)

You can extends the LineFormatter and overload the constructor to use your format instead of the default one.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, that is a great tip. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have solved the problem :-( I am still getting the timestamp in its elongated format. Is this a UTC format?

Comment: This is the difference I get with use_microseconds on/off  
[2022-10-20T15:32:00+00:00] app.NOTICE: alert [] []  
[2022-10-20T15:34:41.309420+00:00] app.NOTICE: alert [] []

Comment: Yes, this is a UTC format. Milliseconds disappeared, but UTC... I didn't find configuration option to remove it.

Comment: that's odd as I have 2 different systems saving logs with 2 different timestamp formats. Thanks though.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a solution to remove UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my custom class to change date format of LineFormatter.
This new format turns `[2022-10-18T09:11:04.228289+00:00]` into `[2022-10-18 09:11:04]`.

Basically you just need to create a new class extending \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter and in the constructor you may set your dateFormat of your choice.

```
namespace App\Formatter;

class CustomLineFormatter extends \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
{
    public function __construct(?string $format = null, ?string $dateFormat = null, bool $allowInlineLineBreaks = false, bool $ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra = false, bool $includeStacktraces = false)
    {
        $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
        parent::__construct($format, $dateFormat, $allowInlineLineBreaks, $ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra, $includeStacktraces);
    }
}
```

Then in config/packages/monolog.yaml you need to specify the path to your custom formatter

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            formatter: App\Formatter\CustomLineFormatter
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).